# Displaying json html data inside a div

Tags: javascript, html, json, fetch

I am trying to display some html from a json file into a div of my web site, but have only managed to get it displayed in the console. 
This is my code so far:

```html
<div id="customSidebar" onload="sidebarContent()">
</div>

<style>
    #customSidebar {
        background-color: green;
        position: fixed;
        top: 120px;
        left: 100px;
        z-index: 100000;
        width: 300px;
        min-height: 300px;
        height: auto;
    }
</style>


<script>
    function sidebarContent(){
        fetch('*url*', {
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*'
            }
        })  

        .then(response => {
            return response.json().then(data => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    return data.mainContent;
                } else {
                    return Promise.reject({status: response.status, data});
                }
            });
        })
        .then(result => console.log('success:', result))
        .catch(error => console.log('error:', error));
    }

    document.getElementById('customSidebar').innerHTML = sidebarContent();
</script>
```

Can anyone tell me what I am missing/have done wrong? 
Thanks!`

Comment: Set the inner html of the div to the html you want to display.

Comment: can you tell what you can see if you put console to `data.mainContent` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result of your function is promise, not string content. So you need to use resolved value for assignment:

```
function sidebarContent() {
    return fetch('*url*', {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*'
        }
    })
    .then(response => {
        return response.json().then(data => {
            if (response.ok) {
                return data.mainContent;
            } else {
                return Promise.reject({ status: response.status, data });
            }
        });
    });
}

sidebarContent().then(content => document.getElementById('customSidebar').innerHTML = content);
```